# js Setting function as variable or anonymous function returning the function

Tags: javascript, function

Okay, so I was wondering something. I just saw the following code:

```
transform = function(e) {
    return Math.log(e);
}
```

But when I do the following code, it works the exact same way

```
transform = Math.log;
```

Is there any reason why you would use the upper one instead of the lower one?

Comment: Also it would matter if `log` relied on `this` for it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the function.

If a function take more arguments, then you could prevent to use this arguments by taking an own function.

```js
function parseInt10(v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10);
}

console.log(['01', '11', '12'].map(parseInt10));
console.log(['01', '11', '12'].map(parseInt));
```

Comment: So in case of the Math.log function, which only has one parameter and it doesn't have to do anything else, it's not a bad thing to use the lower code?

Answer (score 0):

The top option would be used if you were trying to assign the function that variable, so you could alter the way the function works in different situations. you can also assign it to an onclick, onhover, things of that sort. The bottom option, however, does not allow it to be connected to those events, and can still be customized. When you define a variable as a function, it gives more uses/possibilities to it. But this all depends on how you are using the function, whether there are other arguments inside, or not.